Does functional limit iff sequential limit require a contradiction argument?
I've been reading trying to understand the proof of the following theorem. This statement has been taken from Shiffrin's Multivariable Mathematics (Prop 3.6).

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $\mathbf{f} : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $\mathbf{f}$ is continuous at $\mathbf{a}$ iff for every sequence $\left\{\mathbf{x_n}\right\}$ of points in $U$ converging to $\mathbf{a}$, the sequence $\left\{ \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x_n}) \right\}$ converges to $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$.

The forward direction ($\Rightarrow$) feels straightforward, but the reverse ($\Leftarrow$) seems less intuitive to me. Shiffrin employs a contradiction argument, assuming that $f$ is not continuous in the sense of functional limits and then showing that $f(x_n)$ cannot converge to $f(a)$.
My original (admittedly less elegant) idea for this proof was to, given an $\varepsilon >0$, provide a $\delta > 0$ by explicitly constructing some potentially infinite family of sequences.
To elaborate on this idea, let $\varepsilon >0$. If we could find some kind of family of sequences $x_n^i$ converging to $a$, for each one we could find a $N^i$ such that if $n > N_i$, then $|f(x_n^i) - L| < \epsilon$. To each $N^i$ is associated an interval which bounds the set of $x_n$ for $n > N^i$. If we could somehow take an intersection of all of these intervals, the size of the resulting interval could provide a $\delta$? Clearly, this doesn't work without serious modification (for all sequences converging to $a$, I think the intersection is empty).
Is it possible to come up with an explicit formula for a $\delta$ or make the above argument valid without resorting to proof by contradiction?
Thank you so much!
